# Почему в обоих случаях неожиданный результат?

Tags: javascript

В общем наткнулся вот на такой [код](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BrAiiGAwHWsdz01w):

```js
var x = 9027199254741024;
console.log(x);
x = x + 1;
console.log(x);
```

Почему в обоих случаях один и тот же результат?

Если убрать один десяток, то все нормально складывается.

Если добавить десяток к начальному x, то тоже все нормально складывается=>переполнений никаких нету.

А если сделать так, то вообще 2 отнимается вместо 1:

```js
var x = 9027199254741010;
console.log(x);
x = x - 1;
console.log(x);
```

Вроде бы, тут все логично и складываются числа, а не строки.

Почему поведение такое неожиданное?

P.S Вопрос не является дублем, так как там идет речь про отображение, а конкретно тут про арифметику.

Comment: `9027199254741024 + 2 === 9027199254741024` - true  
`9027199254741025 + 1 === 9027199254741024` - false. Интересно :)

Comment: @smellyshovel http://joyreactor.cc/post/3784017 =D

Comment: Весело, конечно, но JS сам по себе тут ни при чем :)

Comment: Так тот вопрос совсем про другое. В том вопросе речь идет про отображение, а тут про арефметику.

Comment: @iluxa1810, то же самое. Представь что сложение отработало: то что ты видишь в результате и есть _отображение_ результата.

Comment: @Grundy, т.е вы хотите сказать, что складывается все правильно, но отображается неверно?

Comment: @iluxa1810, нет, я хочу сказать, что если ты вместо - `9027199254741010-1` попробуешь вывести `9027199254741009` - то все равно получишь тот же результат.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Константа `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` имеет значение 9007199254740991. Смысл этого числа в том, что в JavaScript используется формат чисел с плавающей запятой двойной точности, как определено в стандарте `IEEE 754`, а он может безопасно представлять числа только в диапазоне от -(2^53 - 1) до 2^53 - 1.

[Источник](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)